# THREE.js - Shifting a texture on a Mesh constructed from a TubeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem that I suspect has a very simple answer (one or two lines), but nothing I've tried so far is working.  Many thanks for any suggestions.

What I have is a TubeGeometry and a Texture that I've made via canvas drawing.  I then make a mesh (multi-material object if that makes a difference), and one of the materials has the map property specified as my texture.  I'll call this material Mat.

The problem is that I need a way to continuously rotate the texture around the tube (in torus terms, around the meridians, not the equators).  Kind of like kneading circular bread. Previously I was specifying an offset (0-1) and had a function createTexture(offset) for redrawing the texture on the canvas to mimic wraparound, constantly using the code

`Mat.map = new THREE.Texture( createTexture(offset) );
Mat.map.needsUpdate = true;
Mat.needsUpdate = true;`

Aesthetically, this works fine... except that that the canvas drawing is way too expensive and my performance suffers massively for it.  So it's not a reasonable solution.

I also tried messing around with the `Mat.map.offset` property, but that isn't working at all.  Seems to be leaving the original texture present and overwriting only parts of it. I can't discern exactly what's going on there, and wonder if it's a problem with using TubeGeometry because a related stackExchange question about Spheres was solved by this method.

A third thought was to go into `TubeGeometry.faceVertexUvs` and shift all the face coordinates around, modding by one, as in:

```
function transform(n){       
       var faceVertexUvs = tubeGeometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
       for (var i =0; i < faceVertexUvs.length; i++){
               for (var j=0; j< 3; j++){
                        faceVertexUvs[i][j].y = ((faceVertexUvs[i][j].y + n) % 1);     
               }     
        }
        tubeGeometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

This comes sooo close to working, but always leaves one equatorial line where everything goes wrong.  The texture looks terrible like it were having a great crisis of indecision, and the ray-casting I'm doing goes nuts at this spot too.  99% of it works just fine tho... Maybe there's a way to salvage this last attempt?

I'm not attached to any one method, though. maximum efficiency is extra appreciated!

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: should have mentioned: using r69.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a fragment shader:

```
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform float iGlobalTime;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

varying vec2 vUv;  
void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;
    uv.y = uv.y + iGlobalTime;
    if (uv.y > 1.)
        uv.y = uv.y - 1.;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( iChannel0,  vec2(uv.x, uv.y));
}
</script>
```

Define your shader material:

```
_uniforms = {
    iGlobalTime:    { type: 'f', value: 0.1 },
    iChannel0:  { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/cat.png') },
};
newMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: _uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent,
} );
```

Then set iGlobalTime in your render loop:

```
_uniforms.iGlobalTime.value += clock.getDelta();
while (_uniforms.iGlobalTime.value > 1.)
    _uniforms.iGlobalTime.value -= 1.;
```

Complete working example here: http://rwoodley.org/MyContent/SO/01/

Comment: I'll check this out, demo seems like what I'm looking for.  Any way to stay within the confines of the three.js library tho? I think this is something that three.js should be capable of doing with ease.  I'm pretty certain I can modify your suggestion for my purposes tho so I'll give that a go in the meantime.

Comment: At some point it is simpler to write a simple shader instead of adding more obscure options to three.js objects. But of course it is a judgment call.

Comment: I removed iResolution from the code here. It was extraneous.

Comment: good point about obscuring the library... the judgement call is well beyond my grasp.  
The problem for me is that, although the shader satisfies my needs in some regards (the rotational problem that I posted about is definitely solved by your code, just finished the implementation a moment ago), everything else looks worlds worse.  For starters, the lighting is no longer compatible.  This is daunting to me because I've never worked with shaders directly before.

Comment: I'm also experiencing a serious dip in frame-rate from my previous use of a MeshLambertMaterial

Comment: Well, figured out after some trial and error how to mimic lighting and whatnot with a dot product in the fragment shader.  Still a bit confused about why my frame-rate dipped but all told you have solved my problem, so many thanks for that! I've also realized that I should have tried to better understand shaders a long time ago, they aren't so bad at all, and I'm having a hell of a time messing around with them now.  So many thanks for that too!

Comment: Just put a stats timer in my example. Seems to be hitting 60fps.

Answer (score 0):

The seam is created by the % 1. Remove the % 1 and enable wrapping on the texture (map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping and/or map.wrapT). This will allow you to keep incrementing the UVs and the texture will wrap on itself. You could also try changing map.offset which may just offset the texture for you.

Comment: Getting rid of the %1 did seem like a good idea, i've had problems with javascript's % 1 inaccuracy in the past... 
but this did not seem to work.  I added the lines about map.wrapS and map.wrapT... no good. I think those are default settings anyway?

Comment: Ah I didn't see the link to your working demo. There's nothing wrong with it. The texture is just matted on different colors (what it looks like if there is no alpha layer).

Add this line to your init code:

newMaterial.transparent = true;